# Is It Possible To Update or Remove Part of a URL by Running a SQL Query in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have links which i want to update running a SQL query in phpMyAdmin

http://local.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/11/image.jpg

to this:

http://local.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/image.jpg

I just need to remove sites/4 from the links.

I did try the following:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://local.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/4', 'http://local.dev/wp-content/uploads') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Comment: Query looks fine. Do you get any error while running it? Also make sure that you have committed the data before viewing.

Comment: No error. Using Desktopserver. Not sure this works for part of a URL. committed the data . What does this mean?

Comment: How do u confirm this doesn't work. Do you get some information like "n rows commited" or something like that. Run `select guid from  wp_posts  WHERE post_type = 'attachment';` before and after the update statement.

Comment: I checked the links in the WordPress editor and they didn't change. There was NO confirmation that it completed successfully.

Comment: Maybe i'm using the wrong tab which is Query because it doesn't allow me to paste code to run the query using the SQL tab.

Comment: Cant comment on it, but logic/syntax wise, the query looks fine.

Comment: Success but # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). Links NOT updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure,

From the "Search" tab, click the "Find and replace" second level tab:

[image: Find and replace dialog]

Enter the text you want to find and what you want to replace it with. In this case; we want to find `/sites` and remove it entirely (or, rather, replace it with nothing). You also have to select the column to search from the dropdown.

[image: Find and replace fields]

Once you click "Go" you'll see a preview of all the changes about to be made. Verify that you're not inadvertently changing something like `http://local.dev/site/newpage` or `http://local.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2000/05/site.png` where the search term is accidentally in another portion of the search term.

[image: Preview page]